# Consume asynchronous wcf service synchronously in for loop

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

In my Silverlight application. I have to consume WCF services. Now the question is I want to consume asynchronous wcf service synchronously in for loop.

The service is sort of

```
private void GetCurrentDateTimeServiceCall(int i)
{
    ExportWcfClient proxy = new ExportWcfClient();
    proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted += ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
    proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeAsync(i);
}
```

Now I call the service in the code.

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
   a[i] =something;
   GetCurrentDateTimeServiceCall(i);
    list = a[i]*.895+a[i]*a[i];
   blah blah
 }
```

The question is because the service is asynchronous. It is hard to make consuming the service synchronously.  Originally I put the second service call inside the the completed method of the first service call. The third one is put in the second one of the completed method etc.

But in a for loop the length is various. We don't know the number. And the service is same just pass the different integer in it.

By the way, I use Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4. So I can't use async/await skills.
Thanks for help.

**Edit**

Because the service is asynchronous, so sometimes the code below `GetCurrentDateTimeServiceCall(i);` may run first. For example, `list = a[i]*.895+a[i]*a[i];` run before the service call. That is not expected. I can't access the service side code. Also I can't touch app config as it is in the our data access layer framework. So maybe I need a flag or event or while loop to force the entire flow running synchronously.

Comment: By the way, you can: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/10/22/using-asyncawait-without-net-framework-4-5/

Comment: @PeterBons. Don't think so. It requires Visual Studio 2012 and Nuget. I don't have them in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: ah too bad..my mistake, didn't know 2012 was the minumum

Answer (score 0):

WCF clients support synchronous calls. They should have been generated as well. There should be a method `GetCurrentDateTime`. If you for some reason require an async API generate a client that is `Task` based (TAP, not EAP). Then, if you want to do it synchronous and for some reason cannot use the synchronous method directly, you can use `Task.Wait()` to block.

Note, that the server is independent from the client in the sense that the client can be sync or async regardless of what the server does internally. It is *always* possible to call a WCF service sync and async.

Comment: Yes. But my understanding is Silverlight only use async. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937(v=vs.95)).

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&ei=#complete=1&hl=en&q=silverlight+synchronous+web+service+call, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31018/Synchronous-Web-Service-Calls-with-Silverlight-Dis Does this resolve your issue? In any case you can generate TAP and use Wait(), as explained. You can also wait with EAP in a more awkward way.

Comment: I can't use channelfactory in my case. I want to use Task and Wait to make a try. But still no clue. Should I change the void method as Task? Need code for that.

Comment: You need to detail the exact problem you are having. I have given you multiple approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully it gave the details.

Comment: Did you not just repeat what was stated before? Not sure. You can force the calls to behave synchronously using the techniques I linked to. Why does that not work?